# UIVisualEffectView turning gray (not working)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, interface-builder, uivisualeffectview

My app has an interface that is set up so that when I click a button, a view controller will be presented modally. In that view controller, there is nothing but a `UIVisualEffectView`. When I run my app, it works but then after a second the `UIVisualEffectView` turns gray. Why is it doing that?

Here is a link to a GIF showing my problem:
[click here to view gif](https://ibb.co/ntMZ1J)

Comment: Present your modal view controller over current context.

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: I created it with Interface Builder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the way you present your `UIVisualEffectView` over the background view. Since you are using some sort of full-screen presentation the underlying view is stopped being updated in order to save resources.

You should be able to get this to work by adjusting the presentation style, such as:

`myEffectView.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext`

### Edit

Since you said in a comment that you're using Interface Builder, you can also adjust this there by selecting your `UIViewController` that contains the `UIVisualEffectView` and adjusting its properties:

[image: Adjusting presentation style in Interface Builder]

Comment: @Tofix Cool, then you could also apply your bounty so the "featured" page is less cluttered. :)